# what happens to finally block in the following cases?

Tags: java

if i have a following code

```
      try{

           //some code

      }catch(Exception e){

           //some code

      }finally{

      }
```

what happens to the finally block in the following cases

1. if any checked exceptions happen.
2. if System.exit() is called.
3. if any unchecked exceptions happen.
4. if any errors happen.

Comment: See also http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.20.2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. `finally` block is executed.
2. `finally` block is not executed unless System.exit() throws an Exception, in which case the `finally` block is executed. (see [How does Java's System.exit() work with try/catch/finally blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410951/how-does-javas-system-exit-work-with-try-catch-finally-blocks))
3. `finally` block is executed.
4. `finally` block is executed (depends on the type of error though, if you're talking about a JVM error, then there's really no telling what might happen).

Comment: Unless `System.exit` throws a `SecurityException`.

Answer (score 3):

#### [JLS 14.20.2 Execution of try-catch-finally](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.20.2)

Everything's spelled out pretty clearly. `finally` will always be executed in all of those cases, with the obvious exception of a successful `System.exit`.

#### [`System.exit(int status)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29)

> ***Terminates*** the currently running Java Virtual Machine [...] This method never returns normally.

Answer (score 2):

1. `Finally` will be executed.
2. `Finally` won't be executed, unless `System.Exit()` throws an exception.
3. `Finally` will be executed.
4. `Finally` will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

- 1 and 3 - The `catch` clause will be triggered, and after that - the `finally` clause
- 4 - only the `finally` clause will be triggered
- 3 - the program will exit and `finally` won't be executed. It's because "This method never returns normally. " The `finally` will be triggered in case `System.exit(0)` throws an exception (`SecurityException`)

Comment: To be pedantic, the System.Exit can throw a SecurityException and the finally will be executed:)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that none of the 4 items happens in the finally block, then the finally block will be executed before the code exits unless the VM crashes, then all bets are off.
**EDIT**
`System.exit()` actually bypasses `finally {}`.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to escape a finally clause is System.exit. Every other case the finally block is reached.

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-1997/jw-02-hood.htm

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/exceptions.doc.html (section 11.3)

are good reads about this.

Answer (score 0):

1.if any checked exceptions happen.
  code flows as

a. try...   
   b. [checked exception]  
   c. skip the rest of try and execute  catch block for the checked exception
   d. execute finally

2.if System.exit() is called.
   finally is executed. 
3.if any unchecked exceptions happen.
  a. try...
  b. [unchecked exception]
  c. skip the rest of try and move to finally
  d. execute finally

4.if any errors happen.
 a.finally is executed.But the program is toast before JVM throws an "Error"