# Variable not initialized in try catch block `finally`

Tags: java, syntax, compiler-errors

Why doesn't the compiler understand that the variable is initialized in either the `try` or the `catch` block 
and complains at the `finally` block?

```
int i;
try {
    i = 0;
}
catch (Exception e) {
    i = 2;
}
finally {
    System.out(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you print variable 'i' in catch block before initialization, it gives error because compiler thinks that an exception might be thrown before 'i' has been set in try block in which case 'i' would not have been initialized so is the case with finally here i.e. when you print 'i' in finally block compiler thinks that an exception might be thrown before 'i' has been set in catch block in which case 'i' would not have been initialized

Compiler doesn't understand that the variable is initialized in either the try or the catch block. Compiler complains because local variables should be declared and initialized at the same time but you have just declared it. If you use it in either block (try, catch, finally) without initialization compiler complain about it. Try it:

```
    int i;
    try {
        System.out.println(i);
        //i = 0;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(i);
        //i = 2;
    }
    finally {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

If the initialization statement (`i = 0;`) fails, then the program will continue with the `finally` block, where the variable will still be un-initialized and this is why you get a compile-time error.

Comment: Omg face palm off course the `finally` needs to be executed before the `catch`

Comment: Why do you say the finally block will be preformed before the catch? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109353/what-comes-first-finally-or-catch-block

Comment: So according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109353/what-comes-first-finally-or-catch-block `catch` should run before the `finally` then why does the compile complains

Comment: Compiler complains because local variables should be declared and initialized at the same time but you have just declared it.

Comment: @user1203153 thats not true as far as i know http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/defAssign.html

Comment: In your code, it complains at finally block just because you are trying to use a variable without being initialized. finally block doesn't know whether the variable is initialized or not due to its scope. Your above link proves my point.

Comment: Thanks, very informative link. So if compiler is sure about some statements it acts accordingly e.g. unreachable statement. In your case compiler knows it will surely execute the finally block, then any variable being used in this block should be already initialized. just put this code in your finally block above print statement to verify 
                while (true) {
                 i =1;
                 if (i >= 5) break;
         }

Comment: What i think i was missing is that the compiler assumes that the `try`can fail but also the assignment in the `catch` can also fail therefore when reaching the `finally` its possible the variable wont be initialised is that it ?

Comment: You're right, If you print variable 'i' in catch block before initialization, it gives error because compiler thinks that an exception might be thrown before 'i' has been set in try block in which case 'i' would not have been initialized so is the case with finally here i.e. when you print 'i' in finally block compiler thinks that an exception might be thrown before 'i' has been set in 
catch block in which case 'i' would not have been initialized

Answer (score 2):

The compiler won't be able to know if `i` will get initialized or not. It might fail for whatever reason and therefor the `finally` block might not work.