# Why this code is coming first in finally and then catch block?

Tags: java, exception, finally

```
package testing;

public class ExceptionHandling {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
        int a=10;
        int b=0;
        int c=a/b;
        ExceptionHandling exp = null;
        System.out.println(exp);
        throw new NullPointerException();

        }catch(ArithmeticException e){
            System.out.println("arithmetic issue");
            throw new ArithmeticException();
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e){
            System.out.println("nullpointer");

        }
        finally{

            System.out.println("exception");
            //throw new ArithmeticException();
        }

    }

}
```

In console I am getting this:

```
arithmetic issue
exception
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException
    at testing.ExceptionHandling.main(ExceptionHandling.java:15)
```

But why it gets printed finally block statement first and then catch block statement? It should print catch block statement first and then finally block statement.

Comment: Your output prints `catch` block first and then `finally`. Why do you think it's printing otherwise.

Comment: Check this answer. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109353/what-comes-first-finally-or-catch-block). Also, you don't need to throw exception in try block itself.

Answer (score 2):

This line in the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException
    at testing.ExceptionHandling.main(ExceptionHandling.java:15)
```

Is not being printed from your `catch` block. It's printed after your program leaves finally.

Here's how execution goes.

1. Exception occurs in `try`.
2. `catch` catches that exception.
3. `arithmetic issue` is printed from `catch` block.
4. next line re-throws that exception.
5. your program is about to leave `catch`, but before it leaves, it executes finally block's code. That's why you see word `exception` in your console. That's how `finally` is designed to work.
6. And at last you see actual exception on console when your program ultimately leaves this method.

Answer (score 1):

it does not running first, the way `println` works is concurrent with the exception output. so they may print in various orders

Comment: That output is consistent with order of execution. There is no "various orders" observed in the question.

Comment: @Andreas "That output is consistent with order of execution" this is not true, i've run the exact code above and had [this](http://imgur.com/DdDYNyB) ("exception" printed in middle of the error handling)  but in this case my answer is not true neither. i mean the order of execution is really the way he said.

Answer (score 1):

This is how the flow goes:

1. the `catch` statement catches the exception, prints the message but also throws the exception again
2. the `finally` block is executed, so its message is printed
3. the exception thrown in the `catch` is raised, since from the `catch` it's not been handled anyhow

Answer (score 0):

**Exceptions `thrown` by `main()` method will be handled by JVM** and
because you have recreated the `ArithmeticException` in your `catch` block and `thrown` it from the `main` method then the **JVM has caught your `ArithmeticException` thrown by the `main()` method** and printed the stacktrace on the console.

Your program flow is as follows:

(1) `ArithmeticException` `thrown` by the try block

(2) `ArithmeticException` has been caught by `catch` block and **recreated a `new` `ArithmeticException` and `thrown`** (by this `main()` method)

(3) `finally` block has been executed and printed the given text

(4) **`ArithmeticException` thrown by this `main()` method has been caught by JVM**

(5) **JVM printed the stacktrace of the exception**

To understand this concept better, just `throw` the exception from a different method and catch it from my `main()` as shown below:

```
    //myOwnMethod throws ArithmeticException
    public static void myOwnMethod() {
        try{
            int a=10;
            int b=0;
            int c=a/b;
            throw new NullPointerException();
        } catch(ArithmeticException e){
            System.out.println("arithmetic issue");
            throw new ArithmeticException();
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e){
            System.out.println("nullpointer");
        }
        finally{
            System.out.println("exception");
        }
    }

    //main() method catches ArithmeticException
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            myOwnMethod();
        } catch(ArithmeticException exe) {
            System.out.println(" catching exception from myOwnMethod()::");
            exe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But in your case, your `main()` has thrown the exception and the JVM has caught that Exception.