# statement.executeQuery() mystery. Code not being executed, nor exception is being caught.

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement, executequery

Providing the code and the output. Searched the internet but didn't find solution. Everything compiles and runs okay, up until "**//PROBLEMATIC LINE**", where execution goes directly to "**//HERE**" without any indication, exception or error. I have used this code with the jdbc driver for SQLServer many times and works fine, what am I possibly missing here? In the same application I am also using this code with mySql jdbc driver and again, works fine. Just in this piece of code it is that there is a problem. Obviously I am using java.sql.*; .

```
try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        setResponse("Failure. 1");
        connectionTest = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        setResponse("Failure. 2");
        String query = "SELECT TOP (1) [id] FROM "+ table + ";";
        PreparedStatement statement = connectionTest.prepareStatement(query);
        setResponse("Failure. 3");
        System.out.println(statement);
        ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery();  //PROBLEMATIC LINE
        System.out.println("DOES NOT EVEN PRINT THIS");
        setResponse("Failure. 4");
        if (resultset.first()) setResponse("Success.");
        else setResponse("Failure. 5");
        System.out.println("Query success: ");  
        setResponse("Failure. 6");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            connectionTest.close();  //HERE
            return getResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return getResponse();
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
------------------------------------
-------------DATABASES--------------
------------------------------------
SQLServerPreparedStatement:1
Failure. 3
------------------------------------
----------TESTS COMPLETED-----------
------------------------------------
```

Comment: Your output doesn't show "Failure. 1" or "Failure. 2". What's up with that?

Comment: Java has 2 types of throwable objects, Exceptions and Errors. Your catch block catches only `Exception` while `Error` might be thrown (although it is not likely). Try catching `Throwable` to see if that is the case (and printStackTrace() will print something useful).

Comment: "where execution goes directly to "//HERE" without any indication, exception or error". That is impossible. There is an exception, you just don't seem to print it correctly. Where does your `System.err` stream point to?

Comment: @nicomp My output prints only the value returned from the method.

Comment: Please provide the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel there was no stacktrace, the reason why is marked as the answer below

Comment: If you got an "exception in thread main", there must be a stacktrace on the console or in the logs. There is no other way.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel there was not "exception in thread main" till I did what O.O.Balance suggested below. Now the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an exception is thrown, the `try` block will exit. When the `try` block exits, the `finally` block will be executed. Since you have `return` statements in your `finally` block, you will never get to the `catch` block.

Don't `return` in your `finally` block. Then the stacktrace will get printed and you can deal with the exception.

Comment: the `finally` block executes **before** the first `catch` block?

Comment: Yes, it does. See here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Comment: @O.O.Balance how can I not return in the finally block... my method must return a statement. If an exception is not thrown, finally must return..

Comment: that basically says that `The finally block always executes when the try block exits`. i meant if an exception is thrown in the `try` block. if that's the case, `catch` will be executed and only **then** `finally`, right? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109353/what-comes-first-finally-or-catch-block

Comment: @MaralKay How about writing `return getResponse();` _after_ the `finally` block? Then your method will return something whether an exception is caught or not.

Comment: @O.O.Balance thank you, I totally forgot to place a return statement *after* the finally block.

Answer (score 0):

As the others mentionned, you should do the try-catch thing a little bit different. My recommendation:

```
try {
    Class.forName(driver);
    setResponse("Failure. 1");
    connectionTest = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    setResponse("Failure. 2");
    String query = "SELECT TOP (1) [id] FROM "+ table ;
    PreparedStatement statement = connectionTest.prepareStatement(query);
    setResponse("Failure. 3");
    System.out.println(query);
    ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery(); 
    while ( resultset.next() {
        System.out.println("only one result because of 'top (1)': " + rs.getInt(1));
    }
     resultset.close();
     statement.close();
     connectionTest.close();        
} catch { SQLException sqlex) {
    System.out.println(getClass().getName() + " SQLException:  " + sqlex.getMessage();
}  catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(getClass().getName() + " GenericException:  " + e.getMessage();
     e.printStrackTrace();
}
```

And if all the needed libraries are in the classpath, especially the JDBC-Driver, it should go fine