# Understanding basic Java-specific interverview questions

Tags: java

Last day I faced an interview and they asked me java questions among which for some questions I didn't know the answer. I am curious to know the answer for that question. Interviewer did not tell me the answer. I am asking that questions here:

- Does Java provide any construct to find out the size of an object?
- Give a simplest way to find out the time a method takes for execution without using any profiling tool?
- What are checked exceptions and runtime exceptions?
- If I write return at the end of the try block, will the finally block still execute?
- If I write System.exit (0); at the end of the try block, will the finally block still execute?

Want to know answers of above question so that it can help me next time.

Explanations, notes, and/or relevant links to the specification would be greatly appreciated over just the simple answers -- and what is a good way to learn this stuff?

Comment: -1 Man... here I was expecting interesting questions... I don't think this is a good question (e.g. the information is easily researchable and testable and likely incredibly duplicative) -- however, I hope that some good detailed replies come out of it.

Comment: Given that you now have access to a compiler/run-time & Google, what do **you** think the answers are?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think that all of these can be answered by searching for existing Stack Overflow questions.  The reason I think it's worth answering this question with links to previous answers is that you've asked about a lot of different issues, each one of which is interesting in its own right.  It's not so likely you'll get an in-depth discussion of these when asking about them all together, but in the answers and comments on previous questions here you'll find a lot of detail and discussion which (a) may be interesting and (b) may help in further interviews.  (There may well be better choices - these are just the first reasonable SO answers I found.)

> Does Java provide any construct to find out the size of an object?

- [In Java, what is the best way to determine the size of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object)
- [sizeof java object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115239/sizeof-java-object)

> Give a simplest way to find out the time a method takes for execution without using any profiling tool?

- [How do I time a method's execution in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180158/how-do-i-time-a-methods-execution-in-java)

> What are checked exceptions and runtime exceptions?

- [Differences between Runtime/Checked/Unchecked/Error/Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162760/runtime-checked-unchecked-error-exception)

> If I write return at the end of the try block, will the finally block still execute?

- [Does finally always execute in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035/in-java-does-return-trump-finally)

> If I write System.exit (0); at the end of the try block, will the finally block still execute?

- [How does Java's System.exit() work with try/catch/finally blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410951/how-does-javas-system-exit-work-with-try-catch-finally-blocks)

Comment: Sometimes the answer size is small,but to get that content take a lot of research and effort.This is the type of answer which takes a lot of time to search and you did it successfully.Thank you Very nice answer @Mark Longair

Answer (score 3):

> Does Java provide any construct to find out the size of an object?

AFAIK no.

> Give a simplest way to find out the time a method takes for execution without using any profiling tool?

Measure time with `System.currentTimeMillis()`, `System.nanoTime()`.

> What are checked exceptions and runtime exceptions?

For detailed explanation check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162760/runtime-checked-unchecked-error-exception).

> If I write return at the end of the try block, will the finally block still execute?

yes.

> If I write System.exit (0); at the end of the try block, will the finally block still execute?

no.

Answer (score 3):

> Does Java provide any construct to find out the size of an object?

No.

> Give a simple way to find out the time a method takes for execution without using any profiling tool?

```
long t0 = System.nanoTime();
// code to profile
long timeTaken = System.nanoTime() - t0;
```

> What are checked exceptions and runtime exceptions?

A checked exception is any `Throwable` that does not extend from `java.lang.Error` or `java.lang.RuntimeException`.  The java compiler will give you an error if you do not handle or explicitly propagate checked exceptions.

> If I write return at the end of the try block, will the finally block still execute?

Yes

> If I write System.exit (0); at the end of the try block, will the finally block still execute?

Maybe.  If there is a `SecurityManager` then it can throw a `SecurityException` instead of exiting which will trigger the `finally` block.

If your stack is too large, calling `System.exit` might result in a stack overflow exception which would trigger the `finally` block.

Answer (score 1):

> Does Java provide any construct to find out the size of an object?

There is no cross-platform/cross-VM way, as I know.

> Give a simplest way to find out the time a method takes for execution without using any profiling tool?

by create new Date() before and after execution.

> What are checked exceptions and runtime exceptions?

You should wrap checked exceptions into try/catch block

> If I write return at the end of the try block, will the finally block still execute?

yes

> If I write System.exit (0); at the end of the try block, will the finally block still execute?

No.

Answer (score 0):

1.

no, not for objects generally. .length for arrays and strings...

2.

```
final long startTime = System.nanoTime();
final long endTime;
try {
  methodToTime();
} finally {
  endTime = System.nanoTime();
}
final long duration = endTime - startTime;
```

from [How do I time a method's execution in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180158/how-do-i-time-a-methods-execution-in-java)

3.

unchecked exceptions are bugs, see 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html

checked exceptions are for example, invalid user inputs, exceptions that can be handled.

4.

the finally block will still execute

5.

the finally block will not execute

Comment: how do you measure object's size with `.length`. There is no such field in the `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: I think the OP is after something more generic than arrays .length.

Comment: You gain nothing by putting the `endTime` assignment in a finally block because you're not using it unless `methodToTime` completes normally.

Answer (score 0):

> Does Java provide any construct to find out the size of an object?

Not really. You could create an object and note down the memory differences, or perhaps read the spec to see what an object is made up of.

> Give a simplest way to find out the time a method takes for execution without using any profiling tool?

Like this:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
// do something
System.out.println("Time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
```

> What are checked exceptions and runtime exceptions?

Checked exception are exception that are declared in the `throws` section of a routine. Similarly unchecked exctions are those which are not declared, e.g., subclasses of `RuntimeException`.

> If I write return at the end of the try block, will the finally block still execute?

Yup, at least on the sun/oracle jvm. Not pretty though ..

> If I write System.exit (0); at the end of the try block, will the finally block still execute?

Nope

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html getObjectSize ?

Comment: @Andrey, that's a nice method but according to the javadoc it provides an estimate and that's not size.

Comment: @Alex Nikolaenkov it is at least worth mentioning

Comment: @Andrey, @Alex: At least we can say something regarding object size using getObjectSize();

Answer (score 0):

> Does Java provide any construct to
>   find out the size of an object?

No, it does not.

> Give a simplest way to find out the
>   time a method takes for execution
>   without using any profiling tool?

```
long begTime = System.currentTimeInMillis();
x.method();
long endTime = System.currentTimeInMillis();
System.out.println("method running time: " + (endTime-begTime));
```

> What are checked exceptions and
>   runtime exceptions?

Checked exceptions must be caught, or the compiler will flag; runtime exceptions do not require catch blocks.

> If I write return at the end of the
>   try block, will the finally block
>   still execute?

Yes.

> If I write System.exit (0); at the end
>   of the try block, will the finally
>   block still execute?

No.  http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Comment: `System.exit` is not guaranteed to run.  It can be cancelled by the security manager, and more generally, anything that involves a method call can fail if the stack is within one frame of overflowing.

Comment: Not the vanilla case, but you're certainly correct.   Thanks for the education, Mike.

Answer (score 0):

The size of (serializable) objects can be found relatively easily.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

class HowLongIsAPieceOfString {

    public static int getObjectSize(Object object) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(object);
        return baos.toByteArray().length;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Object object = "string";
        System.out.println( "String size: \t" + getObjectSize(object) );

        object = new JButton("Click Me!");
        System.out.println( "Button size: \t" + getObjectSize(object) );

        object = new JTree();
        System.out.println( "Tree size: \t" + getObjectSize(object) );

        object = new Object();
        System.out.println( "Object size: \t" + getObjectSize(object) );
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
String size:    13
Button size:    4347
Tree size:      5628
Exception in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException: java.lang.Object
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1156)
        ...
```

Comment: this is not size of object, but size of object in serialized form. I think these values are more or less valid only for DTO and other transport objects, not for complex ones. It has not much about how much memory object use.