# Using try-finally block inside while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, break, try-finally

I am trying to understand the mechanism when i use finally inside a while loop. 
In the below code. **In finally** line prints and than the while breaks. I was expecting the code not to reach the finally block. Or if it reaches the finally block, there is **no break** there so the while should continue.. Can anyone explain how this works ?

```
         while(true){
            System.out.println("in while");

            try{
                break;
            }finally{
                System.out.println("in finally");
            }

        }
        System.out.println("after while");
```

Output is

```
in while
in finally
after while
```

Answer (score 5):

Although you `break` it is guaranteed that always finally gets execute when try executed.  You can't stope entering the control into finally.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

> The finally block always executes when the try block exits. This ensures that the finally block is executed even if an unexpected exception occurs. But finally is useful for more than just exception handling — it allows the programmer to avoid having cleanup code accidentally bypassed by a return, continue, or break.

There is a reason for the behaviour. It help us.

> it allows the programmer to avoid having cleanup code accidentally bypassed by a return, continue, or break.

Answer (score 2):

In short, whatever you do inside `try` to exit the current loop or function, `finally` gets executed. This is true for any `return`, `break`, `continue` and almost everything else which would lead you anywhere: `try` can (usually) only be left through `finally`.

There are exceptions, however: as OldCurmudgeon notes, System.exit() does – ind the case of success – not make `finally` be executed.

Comment: There are rare exceptions - [System.exit(n)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1410951/823393) avoids the finally.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Thanks, didn't know that.