# How do I return to the main method from another method in the same class (break didn't work)

Tags: java

So I've seen a bunch of other posts about this, but they didn't apply since a) I'm trying to return to the main method while SKIPPING a while loop inside of the main. I'm making a text adventure game and it works in steps (separate methods), by calling the next step from within the step at the end. for example, the first step is `EastStoryline1()`, and the second is `EastStoryline2()`, and at the end of the code for `EastStoryline1()`, it says `"EastStoryline2()"`.

So the actual main is pretty small, since it's just one method looping into the next. There are also 2 while loops in the main. The first comes right after I establish the scanner and    boolean playagain, which basically surrounds the rest of the main starts the game while playagain = true. the second loop comes right after the first, which basically says while def (the players health) > 0, play the events of the game. After the second loop, but still in the first loop, the code calls the method `Die()`, and then asks the player whether they want to play the game.

SO basically, what code do I put inside `Die()` in order to break out of any existing  loop chain and bring it to the next code after `Die()` is called in the main. The problem is that I also use `Die()` in other methods, and each time it's called I want it to return to the code after `Die()` in the main. Here's the code for the main (sorry for bad formatting):

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean playagain = true;
    while(playagain == true)
    {
    while(def > 0)
    {
      TitleScreen("TXT ADVENTURE!");
      System.out.println("Pick a character: Rogue, Paladin, or Priest 
(capitals DO matter!)");
      String character = keyboard.next();
      CharacterChoice(character);
      System.out.println("You wake up on a dusty road, with no memory of who 
you are or how you got here. You can only remember your name, and how to 
fight. To the east lies a small dock with a boat. To the west, there seems 
to be a sand-scarred mountain range. Do you go east, or west?");
      String ew = keyboard.next();
      EastWest(ew);
  }
  Die();
  System.out.println("Do you want to play again?");
  String playornah = keyboard.next();
  if(playornah.equals("yes") || playornah.equals("Yes"))
  {
    playagain = true;
  }
  else
  {
    playagain = false;
  }
  }
}
```

And this was the code for Die I used `system.exit(0)`, but now I want it to return to the main after Die is called there instead of just ending the program):

```
public static void Die()
  {
    System.out.println("GAME OVER");
    System.exit(0); //I tried using break but it wouldn't compile
  }
```

So what to I code in `Die()` in order for (no matter where it's called) return to the main after the spot where `Die()` is called.

Comment: Just get to the end of the method, or use a `return` statement...

Comment: Break can be used only in loops or switch statements. System.exit(0); is used if you want to come out of the program completely without further execution. Comment out // System.exit(0); from your die method, It should solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void Die()
{
    System.out.println("GAME OVER");
    System.exit(0); //I tried using break but it wouldn't compile
}
```

`System.exit(0);` ends the program. If you want to just end the method either:

- Let the method end naturally when it has no more statements. (Just remove `System.exit(0);`)
- Replace `System.exit(0);` with a `return;` statement

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html):

> A method returns to the code that invoked it when it
>
> - completes all the statements in the method,
> - reaches a return statement, or
> - throws an exception (covered later),
>
> whichever occurs first.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return from an external method, How ever you can use a try-finally to return it once you have run your code.

Comment: wait im really confused, what do you mean by try-finally, and what will it do? sry im new

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48681988/using-try-finally-block-inside-while-loop